# How does SQL interpret brackets and the order in them?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In Northwind sample on SQL Server 2017 for instance,

When I use

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE NOT (COUNTRY='UK' AND NOT COUNTRY='USA')
```

It shows customers from every other country AND USA but not the ones from UK

and when I use

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE NOT (COUNTRY='UK' AND COUNTRY='USA')
```

It shows customers from every country INCLUDING USA & UK

I know that for my purposes I can use

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE NOT (COUNTRY='UK' OR COUNTRY='USA')
```

which will show me the results I want.

But I want to know how is

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE NOT (COUNTRY='UK' AND NOT COUNTRY='USA')
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE NOT (COUNTRY='UK' AND COUNTRY='USA')
```

different from

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE NOT COUNTRY='UK' AND NOT COUNTRY='USA'
```

from SQL's POV

Comment: Please include a sample input table, show us the expected output, and then explain the logic behind it.  I can't figure out what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Fairly standard operator precedence and boolean logic rules here. Nothing peculiar to SQL (except the obvious - `COUNTRY='UK' AND COUNTRY='USA'` can never be true because `COUNTRY` can't have both values simultaneously)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I mentioned at the start that I was using Northwind sample database.

Expected output is to show all customers except for those based in USA and UK(I thought that was pretty straightforward. Apologies.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brackets basically making pair of conditions here in your query. When you are placing 2 condition inside (), this means both condition together will return a single True/False. This True/False will then added to other conditions outside (). You are checking 2 conditions inside () and they are joined by a AND which means if both conditions are True, it will return True. If any one is False, this will return False.

For example your first query-

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE NOT (COUNTRY='UK' AND NOT COUNTRY='USA')
```

Your first checking is COUNTRY='UK', which means if the country is 'UK' it will return True. You have added another condition NOT COUNTRY='USA' with a AND operator. This condition will return True when ever country NOT = 'USA'. In combination, both part will return True when the Country = 'UK'. For any other case, at least one side will return False and together they will return False.

So if the COUNTRY='UK', We can Trnsform the condition as-

```
NOT(True AND True) >> NOT(True) >> False
```

So when your country column contains 'UK', its returning FALSE and as a result, you are getting all records with country except 'UK'

In your second query-

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE NOT (COUNTRY='UK' AND COUNTRY='USA')
```

The inner part will always return False as 2 country can not be there at a time. As a result, we can transform your where part in general as-

```
NOT(FALSE) >> True
```

That means it will return True for all case and you are getting results for all country here.

In your third query-

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE NOT (COUNTRY='UK' OR COUNTRY='USA')
```

The inner part will return True if the country is UK or USA. So in case the country is UK or USA we can transform your where part in general as-

```
NOT(True) >> False
```

This means if the country is UK or USA, it returning False and as a result you are getting all other countries in the list except UK and USA. As this query is giving you the expected output, this is basically equivalent to this following query-

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE COUNTRY NOT IN ('UK','USA')
```

Your final query is without () which means both checking are independent and both part of the checking has to be True as you joined them by AND

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE NOT COUNTRY='UK' AND NOT COUNTRY='USA'
```

This is basically a query like-

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE (NOT COUNTRY='UK') AND (NOT COUNTRY='USA')
```

So this is clear if the value is UK or USA, one part of condition will be False and the row will not return in the output. Rows will be there without country UK and US as a result

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Thank you. I could understand clearly what I was missing and you even gave me a way to improve my query(though I was specifically trying to understand the difference between all the 3 methods to get to the same point). I was reminded of how logic gates work and this was kinda like tracing a logic circuit for me who's just starting to learn SQL

Comment: Nice to hear that the answer helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple logic here:

```
NOT (COUNTRY='UK' AND NOT COUNTRY='USA')
```

will be everything NOT (UK), the last part is not required - you have already said excluded country must be UK inside the brackets.

```
NOT (COUNTRY='UK' AND COUNTRY='USA')
```

will return nothing since a country cant be both UK and USA

```
NOT COUNTRY='UK' AND NOT COUNTRY='USA'
```

says any rows that is not either UK or USA

Answer (score 0):

Not COUNTRY ='UK' one can understand every country excluding UK. Why then insert AND NOT 'USA'? I seems logic that inserting AND NOT is also excluding USA.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35169428)